# Replacing System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Encode with System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Protect

Tags: asp.net, encryption, decode, encode

I just upgraded a project from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5.1 which produced the following warning:

> Public Shared Function Encode(data() As Byte, protectionOption As
>   System.Web.Security.MachineKeyProtection) As String' is obsolete:
>   'This method is obsolete and is only provided for compatibility with
>   existing code. It is recommended that new code use the Protect and
>   Unprotect methods instead.'

I have lots of values floating around in cookies and emails that were encrypted with Encode.  If I am going to replace Encode/Decode with Protect/Unprotect, I still need to be able to decrypt those old encrypted values.  Is it possible to Unprotect a value that was encrypted with Encode?

Answer (score 4):

In .NET 4.0 you can use MachineKey API to Protect/Unprotect data like this:

```
string Protect(byte[] data)
{
    if (data == null || data.Length == 0) return null;
    return MachineKey.Encode(data, MachineKeyProtection.All);
}

byte[] Unprotect(string value)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) return null;
    return MachineKey.Decode(value, MachineKeyProtection.All);
}
```

`MachineKey.Encode` accepts a `byte[]` to protect and returns a string. The second parameter is an enum that indicates if you want encryption, validation or both. I’d typically suggest both (`MachineKeyProtection.All`). The returned string can then be used to pass back to the client as a cookie value or a query string value without concern for viewing or tampering. `MachineKey.Decode` simply reverses the process.

And here’s the 4.5 usage:

```
string Protect(byte[] data)
{
    if (data == null || data.Length == 0) return null;
    var value = MachineKey.Protect(data, "");
    return Convert.ToBase64String(value);
}

byte[] Unprotect(string value)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) return null;
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
    return MachineKey.Unprotect(bytes, "");
}
```

In 4.5 the old APIs are deprecated in favor of these new `Protect` and `Unprotect` APIs. The new APIs no longer accept the level of protection (they always encrypt and MAC now [which is good]) and instead now accept a new parameter which is called `purpose`. This purpose parameter is intended to act somewhat as a validation mechanism. If we use a value that’s specific to the user (as we do above with the `GetMachineKeyPurpose` helper) we then are verifying that the value can only be unprotected by the same user. This is a nice addition in 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

No - the process is different. Not to mention you'll be trying to Unprotect data that has no additional parameter specified (which won't work) and sometimes decoding data with the additional parameter specified (if you are ideally taking advantage of how protect works)

I'd refactor the code to be able to tell when the old data is present and write a new cookie/etc out using Protect();

On the first case I mentioned - you cannot use a blank parameter in Protect like

```
var unprotect = MachineKey.Unprotect(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myOldEncryptedStuff), "");
```

and if you in turn have some other code there like "User 12345" to help protect that data - this is called the purpose string and helps keep that string encrypted in a more unique way tied to that user.

```
var unprotect = MachineKey.Unprotect(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myOldEncryptedStuff), "User 12345")
```

If the purpose strings don't match you'll just get a generic exception here like:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred
>   during a cryptographic operation.

So it won't work for you - the two methods operate very differently. You'll need to figure out when to use one vs the other. You could always catch the exception and then try to fallback to the old tech - but test that out :)

Comment: let me know if this works for you - if not how else I can help, if so please accept :)